# Correctly typing a HOC component that returns a component with forwardRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components, react-forwardref

I am trying to make a HOC which returns a component with forwardRef but am not sure how to type it
Here is the code

```
type Omitted = 'variant' | 'size';

export interface InputProps<T extends Omit<T, Omitted>> {
    startIcon?: React.ReactElement;
    endIcon?: React.ReactElement;
}

const withInput = <P extends object>(InputComponent: React.ComponentType<P>) =>
    React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps<P>>(
        ({ startIcon, endIcon, ...props }, ref) => {
            return (
                <InputGroup>
                    {startIcon && (
                        <InputLeftElement>
                            {startIcon}
                        </InputLeftElement>
                    )}
                    <InputComponent ref={ref} {...props} />
                    {endIcon && (
                        <InputRightElement>
                            {endIcon}
                        </InputRightElement>
                    )}
                </InputGroup>
            );
        }
    );

const Input = withInput(InputBaseComponent);

Input.Number = withInput(NumberInputBaseComponent);
```

But am getting two errors
one on the `InputComponent`

```
Type '{ children?: ReactNode; ref: ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null> | null; }' is not assignable to type 'P'.
  '{ children?: ReactNode; ref: ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null> | null; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'
```

and the other is on `Input.Number`

```
Property 'Number' does not exist on type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<InputProps<Pick<InputProps, "variant" | "size" | "left" | "right" | "form" | "p" | "slot" | "style" | "title" | "pattern" | "ref" | "key" | "sx" | "accept" | "alt" | "autoComplete" | ... 514 more ... | "isLoading"> & Pick<...>> & RefAttributes<...>>'.
```

Here is a link to a codesandbox if someone wants to try it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-shape-rwmmg?file=/src/Input.tsx:0-959

Answer (score 0):

### Property 'Number' does not exist

The `Input.Number` error is the easier one to understand.  You are trying to export an object which is a component and has a property `Number` which is a different component.  The error is telling you that you can't set an arbitrary property like `Number` on a component, which kinda makes sense (It is doable, but complicated).  I recommend putting both the `Base` and the `Number` at the same level rather than having one as a property of the other.

```
const Input = {
  Base: withInput(InputBaseComponent),
  Number: withInput(NumberInputBaseComponent)
}
```

Now `Input` is just an object with two different components as properties.

You could also export the various instances individually, and group them together when you import by doing

```
import * as Input from `./Input`
```

### Assigning ...props to 'P'

First of all, I think that your `InputProps` interface isn't doing what you intended for it to do.

```
export interface InputProps<T extends Omit<T, Omitted>> {
  startIcon?: React.ReactElement;
  endIcon?: React.ReactElement;
}
```

This interface says that `InputProps` is an object with an optional `startIcon` and `endIcon`.  That's it.  `T` is never used and doesn't matter.  No props of `T` are included in `InputProps`.  When you spread `InputProps` into `{ startIcon, endIcon, ...props }`, the only prop that's left in `...props` is `children`.  So of course this is going to cause an error when we want `...props` to include all of the props `P` of `InputComponent`.

I think what you meant to say here was that `InputProps<T>` contains those two icons AND all of `T`, except for the omitted properties.

```
export type InputProps<T> = Omit<T, Omitted> & {
  startIcon?: React.ReactElement;
  endIcon?: React.ReactElement;
}
```

This is better because now we've got some actual props in `...props`.  Hovering over it shows

```
Pick<React.PropsWithChildren<InputProps<P>>, "children" | Exclude<Exclude<keyof P, Omitted>, "startIcon" | "endIcon">>
```

So basically we've got everything in `P` plus `children` minus `variant`, `size`, `startIcon`, and `endIcon`.  Is this subset assignable to `P`?  Maybe, but not always, and that's what the error is telling you.

It's common for typescript to have a hard time understanding that the pieces make up the whole when using `{...rest}` syntax.  I often have to assert `as P` in my HOCs.

Regardless of everything in the next few paragraphs, you're still going to end up doing that here:

```
<InputComponent {...props as P} ref={ref} />
```

### Type Safety

Is is really ok to say that `...props` is `P`?  When we use `as`, we are basically telling typescript to hush because we know more than it does.  So we want to make sure that we aren't giving it bad information.

When will {...props} *not* be assignable to `P`?  How can we prevent those instances from occurring?

There is some cause for concern here due to the fact that we `Omit` `variant` and `size` from the props of the inner component, so `...props` (which we want to be `P`) is known by typescript to not contain either of these properties.  If these properties exist on `type P` and are required, then `...props` **cannot** be `P`.  The same is true if `P` includes required properties `startIcon` and `endIcon`, since we pulled those out with the spread.

For `variant` and `size`, I don't really see the point to omitting them at all.  You aren't setting any default values for them, so why not let them be passed through?

But as a general idea, and for `startIcon` and `endIcon`, we need to refine our `P extends` such that if `P` has these properties, they **must** be optional.  We also want to make sure that our `InputComponent` can accept the `ref` type which we are passing it.

You can be more confident that what we are asserting with `as` is accurate if you refine the types like this:

```
interface Dropped {
  variant?: any;
  size?: any;
}

interface Icons {
  startIcon?: React.ReactElement;
  endIcon?: React.ReactElement;
}

export type InputProps<T> = Omit<T, keyof Dropped | "ref"> & Icons;

type PBase = {
  ref?: React.Ref<HTMLInputElement>;
} & Dropped & Partial<Record<keyof Icons, any>>

const withInput = <P extends PBase>(InputComponent: React.ComponentType<P>) => ....
```